# A good response to holiday greeting from professor?

Tags: greetings

I have been discussing some research topics with my professor. He emailed me ending with "Wish you a happy holiday season". What response can I give (as a student) that reflects respect and that does not seem awkward?

Comment: Just wish the professor a happy holiday season...no need to be creative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's conventional to respond with similar words. Sometimes people add "to you too" or some such when the other person initiated the greeting.

Depending on your religious and cultural inclinations, you might say, "Happy holidays to you, too" or "Merry Christmas" or "And I wish you a Happy Hanukkah", etc.

Comment: Is there something more creative that I can respond with? To me, it seems adding '...to you, too' might seem a little lazy. Or am I just projecting too much of my own connotation of the phrase?

Comment: I think you're trying too hard. It's very common in English to give casual greetings and response, "Have a nice day." "You, too" Etc. Yes, you CAN be more creative. But such greetings are pretty much stock formulas. If you're just trying to be friendly or courteous, respond with the stock greeting. Anything else sounds like you're trying to start a conversation or make a point.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this point up with the excellent explanation. I have accepted the answer.